# Identify this SMD TVS

Tags: identification, datasheet, surface-mount, tvs

[image: General Semiconductor LM 47A TVS]

What is this exactly? It measures 0.14" (3.55mm) wide x 0.22" (5.56mm) tall x 0.09" (2.26mm) thick, likely a DO-214AA or SMB package. Circa 2016. Removed and photographed.

Out-of-circuit it measured as an 18v bidirectional TVS using a 100k resistor. See where the Vishay [SM6T18A](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88385/sm6t.pdf) is marked "LM7" and [SMBJ15A](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88392/smbj.pdf) is marked "LM" but these are both uni-directional. Application is bidirectional (IGBT gate clamp.) Thanks for looking.

Comment: The manufacturer's symbol looks like ST electronics or the old SGS Thomson logo.

Comment: I think it's General Semiconductor, now Vishay, but I could be wrong.

Comment: ah you might be right. I' know in the last year I've had to reverse engineer one with this symbol and I forgot about GS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's this one the [SMBG device from Vishay](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88456/smbg.pdf) : -

[image]

The body dimensions don't quite match but maybe you measured it not quite so accurately. If you tried a slightly higher test current like 1 mA it might sit around 18.8 volts.